# jQuery load AND submit form

Tags: html, href

I have a "simple" quest...

I looking for a way to submit AND load...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".navigation").click(function(){
        $("#main").load('demoAvisos_2.asp');
        return (false)
      });

    });

    </script>

</head>

<body><br><br>

<div class="container">
<br>
<!---- cabealho ------>
<div>

</div>
<br>
<!-- +#+#+#+#+#+#+#+ -->
<!------ sidebar1 ----->
    <div class="sidebar1" id="side1">
        <ul class="nav">

            <%
            dasql =" QUERY and call"

            count = 1
            taviso = da.recordcount

            do while not da.eof     
            %>  
                <li>

                <a href="#"  class="navigation"><%=da("aviso")%></a>
                <input type="hidden" value="teste_2" name="r">

                </li>

            <%
            Session("teste_"&count) = da("aviso")
            'Response.Write(Session("teste_"&count))
            count = count+1

            da.movenext
            loop

            Session("count") = count
            'Response.Write(Session("count"))
            %>

        </ul>
    </div>

<!-- +#+#+#+#+#+#+#+ -->
<!------- main -------->
    <div class="content" id="main">


    </div>
<!-- +#+#+#+#+#+#+#+ -->
</div>
```

I need to submit the info at the  by the link at the page demoAvisos_2.asp, and load this at

I just looked at other foruns, but I just found how to load() or to submit() not booth!!

someone can help me?